# Problem in link subdomain in cloudflare to my django app

Tags: django, cloudflare

I have a problem in linking my subdomain on cloudflare to my django app
I have a django app on hetzner cloud  and I managed to run app on its ip but I could not link it to subdomain in cloudflare xxx.example.com it give me web server is down error 521
What do you think about cloudflare?

I managed to run app on hetzner cloud ip